# Using polymer core-pages, select correct page based on url #fragment

Tags: javascript, polymer

I have a polymer app, which uses core-pages and core-menu. This is a minimum working example:

```
<!doctype html> 
<html> <head>
  <script src="/bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-menu/core-menu.html">
  <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-item/core-item.html">
  <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-pages/core-pages.html">
</head>
<body unresolved>

<template is="auto-binding">
<core-menu selected="0" selectedIndex="{{selected}}">
  <core-item label="Item 1"><a href="#foo" target="_self"></a></core-item>
  <core-item label="Item 2"><a href="#bar" target="_self"></a></core-item>
</core-menu>
<core-pages selected="{{selected}}">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
</core-pages>
</template>
```

How do I make it so that if I hyperlink to /example.html#bar that the `<div>two</div>` will be displayed instead of `<div>one</div>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to take a look at the Polymer demo for a single page app with routing. It uses the [flatiron-director](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/flatiron-director) component for hash-routing. Here is the [demo](http://polymer-change.appspot.com/demos/spa.html), and here is the [source code](https://github.com/ebidel/polymer-change/blob/master/demos/spa.html).

I'm currently writing my own router component and things can quickly get very complicated if you want to do pattern matching on deep routes with parameters and update different parts of your page independently (and also want a nice and flexible routing configuration).

But the basic functionality is quite simple. To give each element an id that matches the hash is a good starting point. You can use the `valueattr` attribute to choose another attribute (`id`) for the `selected` value instead of the page index (another option is to stick with the page index and define a mapping from hash-routes to page indexes). Here is a complete example for your scenario:

```
<polymer-element name="my-app">

  <template>
    <core-menu selected="{{selected}}" valueattr="id">
      <core-item id="foo" label="Item 1"></core-item>
      <core-item id="bar" label="Item 2"></core-item>
    </core-menu>
    <core-pages selected="{{selected}}" valueattr="id">
      <div id="foo">one</div>
      <div id="bar">two</div>
    </core-pages>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer('my-app', {
      ready: function() {
        window.onhashchange = function() {
          var page = window.location.hash.substring(1);
          this.selected = page;
        }.bind(this);
        this.selected = 'foo';
      },
      selectedChanged: function() {
        window.location.hash = this.selected;
      }
    });
  </script>

</polymer-element>

<my-app></my-app>
```

I am setting the location hash whenever the selected page changes. The `onhashchange` handler updates the selected page whenever the hash changes (which essentially is the answer to your question, because when the user enters a new hash (directly or by clicking a link), this updates the currently visible page.)

Setting the hash programmatically also calls the `onhashchange` handler, but this is no problem since the `selectedChanged` handler is only called if `selected` has indeed changed. But in the more general case you might need to do more checks here to prevent unwanted updates.

What's missing is a check if the user has entered an invalid route. In this case no page is displayed at all, but you may want to redirect to a default page instead.

Comment: One change I found I had to make, because I ended up making the menu dynamically generated from the pages: I had to use 'domReady' instead of 'ready'.

Answer (score -1):

Just a suggestion, as i'm not an expert on that. Put some IDs (or find another way to get divs) and :

```
if (window.location.href.slice(-3) == "bar")
{
   swap(idOne,idTwo);
}
else
{
   swap(idTwo,idOne);
}

function swap(one, two) {
    document.getElementById(one).style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById(two).style.display = 'none';
}
```